# how to hide horizontal scrollbar in div tag

Tags: html, scrollbar, hidden

I have a `div` with size x=540px y=600px

I want to hide horizontal scroll bar  even if text is bigger than x size.

How can i hide just the horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 21):

use overflow-x

```
<div class="MyDivClass"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.MyDivClass {
    height: 600px;
    width: 540px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

if you also want to hide the vertical use `overflow-y: hidden;` or for both just `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

```
.MyDivClass {
    height: 600px;
    width: 540px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use `overflow-x: hidden` in body tag to hide horizontal scroll bar on whole HTML page**

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #757575;
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 540px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also nicely control that using below code

```
.div{
    width: 540;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```